# How to access the n'th element of a Matlab array by a function instead of indexing

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I am wondering if it is possible to access the n'th element of an array in Matlab by some means other than indexing. What I mean is a function which would act like `nth(a, n)` to return the value of `a(n)`. I tried looking for functions named `nth` or `subscript` or `index` but came up empty-handed.

The reason I ask is that Matlab requires unnamed functions to comprise a single statement, so the obvious workaround to say something like `f = @(mumble, n) tmp = blurf(mumble); tmp(n)` doesn't work, and also the Matlab parser doesn't seem to recognize the expression `blurf(mumble)(n)` where `blurf(mumble)` is a function call which returns an array; I get an error `Invalid array indexing` for that.

I guess I can write my own function to implement getting the n'th element, but I would prefer to use a built-in function.

Comment: The built-in function is [`subsref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html), but it's not trivial to use. It exists to implement indexing for custom classes. You could instead write an anonymous function `nth = @(a,n) a(n)`. But the better solution is to write a regular function instead of an anonymous one where the logic is complex enough that it doesn't comfortably fit in one statement.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `subsref`. Yeah, it looks like introducing `subsref` will make the picture more complicated instead of less ... About an anonymous `nth` function, that occurred to me after I posted the question, and it looks like that's the simplest way forward. Incidentally what I'm trying do is not any more complicated than `blurf(mumble)(n)`, so except for Matlab's inability to deal with the syntax, it's not anything complex. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: You know you can append a regular function to a function or script M-file? They're called "[local function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html)", and are visible only within the file itself. Put an `@` in front of the function name to get a handle. This is much better (faster AND easier to maintain) than an anonymous function that depends on other anonymous functions. Generally, there is no advantage at all to an anonymous function.

Comment: I dunno. Anonymous functions have the very useful property that they capture a lexical closure, so a local function isn't equivalent. I can see that each one could be useful in different circumstances; however, it's something of an overstatement to say "there is no advantage at all to an anonymous function."

Comment: You can also capture local variables using nested functions. But sure, they do have a purpose. I meant in your intended `f = @(mumble, n) blurf(mumble)(n)`. ---- Often people think they need an anonymous function as input to functions such as `ode45`, `fzero`, etc., whereas they just need a handle to a function, it doesn't need to be anonymous.

Comment: Using @gnovice's very apt words in the duplicate, this is "ugly, but possible" :-) An equally ugly, perhaps funnier alternative is `nth = @(a,n) sum(nonzeros(a(:).*(1:numel(a)==n).'));` (`sum` is needed in case the indexed entry is zero, and this doesn't work if `a` contains `NaN` or `inf`)

Comment: Haha, yeah. It occurred to me to do something like that ... I just couldn't bring myself to go through with it.